# Why is Mongo query and Java Mongo Driver query giving me very different results?

Tags: java, mongodb, date, mongodb-query, isodate

Why are these queries giving me very different results?

Mongo version:

```
    db.journeydata.find({"$or" : [{"Start Date" : {'$gte' : ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z"), '$lte' : ISODate("2015-07-01T01:00:00Z")}}, 
    {"End Date" : {'$gte' : ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z"), '$lte' : ISODate("2015-07-01T01:00:00Z")}}]}).count()
```

Java version:

```
    BasicDBObject c1 = new BasicDBObject();
    c1.put("Start Date", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromDate).add("$lt", toDate).get());

    BasicDBObject c2 = new BasicDBObject();
    c2.put("End Date", BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", fromDate).add("$lt", toDate).get());

    BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
    or.add(c1);
    or.add(c2);
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);

    final DBCursor dbCursor = journeyColl.find(query);

    final List<DBObject> journeyDBObject  = dbCursor.toArray();
    final List<Journey> journeyList = new ArrayList<Journey>(journeyDBObject.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < journeyDBObject.size(); i++){
        final DBObject dbObject = journeyDBObject.get(i);
        final Journey journey = createJourney(dbObject);
        journeyList.add(journey);
    }
```

Where, fromDate and toDate are instances of Java.Util.Date. I have absolutely no idea why the queries are giving me different results. They should give me the same result. Any suggestions?

-- EDIT:

This is what mongo profiler gives me:

```
query:{
"$or" : [
    {
        "Start Date" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-30T23:00:00Z"),
            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    },
    {
        "End Date" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2015-06-30T23:00:00Z"),
            "$lt" : ISODate("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
]
```

}

I have no idea why the dates changed? How can I avoid that?

-- EDIT:

This is how I generate the dates, I dont set any time zone:

```
final String begin = "2015-7-1T00:00:00.000Z";
final String end = "2015-7-31T00:00:00.000Z";

final DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
final DateTime beginDateTime = parser.parseDateTime(begin);
final DateTime endDateTime = parser.parseDateTime(end);
```

--- EDIT:

```
final DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Setting timezone solved the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a timezone issue, check your fromDate and toDate creation in Java, do you set a UTC timezone?

Comment: @IoannisLalopoulos I dont set any time zone. Please see my edit, thats how I generate the dates

Comment: @IoannisLalopoulos thanks setting the timezone fixed the problem! :)